# get data in view from viewModel by using class name and function

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to get data in view from viewModel and make it dynamic, i.e. in view i write:

```
*if(AccessControlManager.IsInUserRoles("SEODataEditor",UserRoles))
{
       //hide or show SEODataEditor in layout
}*
```

but in view Model i should define a class AccessControlManager, or outside viewModel and how to access
it in view, through viewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the static method

```
namespace MyApp.Helpers
{
    public class AccessControlManager
    {
        public static bool IsInUserRoles(string role, Role[] userRoles) { ... }
    }
}
```

Then you can access this in your view

```
@if (MyApp.Helpers.AccessControlManager.IsInUserRoles("SEODataEditor", UserRoles)) { ... }
```

You can reference this without the full namespace if you add a `using` statement to the top of the view

```
@using MyApp.Helpers

@if (AccessControlManager.IsInUserRoles("SEODataEditor", UserRoles) { ... }
```

But if you are using an instance method on a View Model then just reference like any other POCO property.

```
@Model.IsInUserRoles("SEODataEditor", UserRoles)
```